# Sockets - select / thread / both

Tags: multithreading, sockets, select

Recently I have learnt about network programming. I know that for server to handle multiple clients, there is a need to use `select` or `Thread` (at least in python/c/c++, I do not know nothing about something similar to `select` in java, in java I only know the thread approach).

I have read that using `select` is better from the performance point of view and threads are better for small servers. However, yesterday I found this page: http://www.assembleforce.com/2012-08/how-to-write-a-multi-threading-server-in-python.h and I do not understand why in the provided code guy uses both `select`  and `threads`? It's difficult for me to understand how does exactly it works and why it is better than other methods I mentioned? I do not understand the idea behind this code.

Thank you.

Comment: What about using a serial bus, RabbitMQ, MuleSoft.  Let the serial bus do the work for you.  Making your application Thread Safe can be quite complex and usually better to let the OS handle this for you.  Might not answer question but these are a different outlet, that works for web development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threads and `select` are not mutually exclusive.

Multi-threading is a form of parallel processing, allowing a single process to seemingly perform multiple tasks in an asynchronous manner.

Using `select` allows your program to monitor a file descriptor (e.g, a socket), waiting for an event.

Both can (and, to my knowledge, are frequently) used together. In a network server environment, threading can be used to service multiple clients, while `select` is used so that one of the threads will not hog CPU time while idling.

Imagine that you are receiving data from multiple clients. A thread is waiting for data from client1, which is taking too long, meanwhile, client2 is sending data like crazy. You have three options:

1. Without `select`, using blocking calls: Block waiting for data from client1, and leave client2 waiting.
2. With `select`, using non-blocking calls: Continuously poll client1, giving up after `n` tries without any data transfer.
3. With `select`: Monitor the clients sockets. If they have data to transfer, read it. Else, relinquish the current thread CPU time.

This is a simple non-blocking approach to network servers, trying to give a low latency response to client. There are different approaches, and for that I recommend you check the book UNIX Network Programming.

Comment: Using your advices, I tried to implement a server with both threads and select. But it seems something is still wrong. Could you please help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43355800/select-thread-multiclient-server-in-python-hangs-after-receiving-after-first-m