# Select / Thread Multiclient Server in Python hangs after receiving first message

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, select

I wanted to write a server which will be able to handle multiple clients sing `select` and `threads`.

I know how to write a server only with `threads`, or only with `select`. Now, I wanted to mix them together. But it seems I failed.

**Server:**

```
import threading
import socket
import select


class Client(threading.Thread):
    '''
    Multi-threading clients.
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        pass

    def setup(self, __client, __address):
        self.client = __client
        self.address = __address

    def connect(self):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def run(self):
        print self.client.__class__
        data = self.client.recv(1024)
        if data:
            self.client.sendall(data)
        else:
            print "Error:", self.address


class Server(object):
    '''
    Threading server
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.bind(('127.0.0.1', 9876))

    def run(self):
        self.server.listen(10)
        inputs = [self.server]
        while 1:
            inready, outready, excready = select.select(inputs, [], []);

            for s in inready:
                if s == self.server:
                    sock, address = self.server.accept();
                    client = Client()
                    client.setup(sock, address)
                    client.start()

        self.server.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = Server()
    server.run()
```

**Client:**

```
import socket
import sys

port = 9876
size = 1024
s = None
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = socket.gethostname()
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))
except socket.error, (value, message):
    if s:
        s.close()
    print "Could not open socket: " + message
    sys.exit(1)
while True:
    data = raw_input('> ')
    s.sendall(data)
    data = s.recv(size)
    print "Server sent: %s " % data
s.close()
```

Client sends and receives only one message and then Im not able to send any more messages. Why? How to improve this? Thank you.

**Edit: One error found. There was a loop missing in Client's run method:**

```
import threading import socket import select


class Client(threading.Thread):
    '''
    Multi-threading clients.
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        pass

    def setup(self, __client, __address):
        self.client = __client
        self.address = __address

    def connect(self):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print self.client.__class__
            data = self.client.recv(1024)
            if data:
                self.client.sendall(data)
            else:
                print "Error:", self.address
                self.client.close()


class Server(object):
    '''
    Threading server
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.bind(('127.0.0.1', 9876))

    def run(self):
        self.server.listen(10)
        inputs = [self.server]
        while 1:
            inready, outready, excready = select.select(inputs, [], []);

            for s in inready:
                if s == self.server:
                    sock, address = self.server.accept();
                    client = Client()
                    client.setup(sock, address)
                    client.start()

        self.server.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = Server()
    server.run()
```

But now, when client disconnects, I have an error on server's side. How to handle this error?

```
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/testserver.py", line 25, in run
    data = self.client.recv(1024)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 174, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: `Client.run` will only serve one send/receive until the thread is killed but the connection remains open.

Comment: @user2896976: Thank you! I somehow missed it. But how about the error on servers side when client disconnects? How to handle it properly?

Comment: Put a `try` block in your `Client.run` method to handle when the socket suddenly disconnects.